# Unsteady flow inside a pipe with heat exchange and pressure drop

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow

I am studying the behaviour of a hot air gas inside a circular-area (constant area $A$) pipe. The gas exchanges heat through the wall and experiences pressure drop while flowing inside the pipe. I want to study the unsteady phase in 1D.

Initially, the hot gas is at rest and at a hot temperature $T_0$ and at pressure $P_0$ inside a tank upstream to the pipe, whereas the pipe wall is at $T_{out}<T_0$ and the air inside the pipe is at rest at $T_{out}$ and at $P_{out}<P_0$

The hot air is an ideal gas (constant $c_p$, $c_v$, $\gamma$).

At the end of the pipe there is a nozzle expelling to the outer atmosphere $P_{out}$, $T_{out}$.

Moreover, I know the pressure drop equation along the pipe (thanks to Idelcik book) : $dP = f(geometry,Reynolds,speed,density)$

I would like to study the transient phase when we open the tank with hot pressured air. I would like to know the governing equations which takes into account the heat exchange, the loss of temperature and the pressure drop.

I know the governing equations for steady flow, and that for steady flow the mass flow $\dot{m}$ is regulated by the choked throat of the nozzle.

However, I don't know the governing equations for unsteady flow, plus I have a problem about the calculation of the mass flow and about the calculation of the pressure drop.

**What are the governing equations of unsteady flow with heat exchange inside the pipe ?**

**Plus how should I consider the pressure drop equation in transient ? Should it be written : $dP = P(x+dx, t+dt) - P(x,t)$ ?**

**And how about the mass flow, how can I calculate it ?** I thought that at first, before the first wave pressure gets to the throat, the mass flow is regulated by Vena Contracta phenomena in the inlet of the pipe creating a kind of virtual nozzle. Is it wrong ?

I know it is a lot of questions at once, but basically **my main problem is : what are the governing equations of unsteady flow inside a pipe with heat exchange and pressure drop along the pipe for 1D flow ?**

The thing is I want to implement a finite difference 1D program to study the transient, and so far it is not running, because I feel like my mathematical model is wrong.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is this for a PhD thesis?  Do you need an equation based solution or can you use something like CFD?  If CFD is appropriate, is there any code that combines CFD with heat transfer?

Comment: No it is not for a PhD thesis, and unfortunately I do not have a CFD tool-like. I only have Python to tackle this problem. I have implemented the equations from the model I have followed, but I am not sure that my equations are right because it is like a mix of several courses. Plus, it gives absurd results so it has to be wrong. As I cannot found a clear model of equations, I am asking for your help.

Comment: I was just curious for more details.  I'm afraid that I can't help, as this is a very difficult problem that involves transient heat transfer, compressible flow, and possibly turbulence.  If turbulence is involved, note that this is one of the main unmodelled problems in physics.

Comment: @DavidWhite If you wish it I can edit my post and write all the continuous equations and the discretized equations that I have implemented. In case your are curious, and, why not, if you have comments or critics to give I would be happy to read them

Comment: Have you considered doing the fluid flow problem first before doing the combined flow and heat transfer?

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes I did, I managed to make it work when I only consider the fluid flow problem with pressure loss (no heat transfer). In order to take into account the heat transfer I use the 1st law of thermodynamics for open systems $\biggl(E(t+\mathrm{d}t) - E(t)\biggr) 
+ \biggl(\mathrm{d}m_{\rm exit}\Bigl(e_{\rm kin exit}(t+\mathrm{d}t)+h_{\rm exit}(t+\mathrm{d}t)\Bigl)
- \mathrm{d}m_{\rm in}\Bigl(e_{\rm kin in}(t)+h_{\rm in}(t)\Bigl)\biggl)
=  Q_{wall} $ But I think I messed up when I tried to apply and develop this formula at local position $x$ to do finite difference method

Comment: For the fluid flow problem, did you solve the Navier Stokes equation(s)?  Are you familiar with the partial differential equations describing the thermal energy balance within a flow system?  Your equation does not include the spatial variations in the energy balance.

Comment: Your analysis screams naively simplistic.  For the development of the equations that need to be used to do this properly, see Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.  Is the flow going to be laminar or is it going to be turbulent?

Comment: The flow is a priori turbulent. I don't solve directly Navier-Stokes. Thanks to the assumption of ideal gas and 1D flow I use equations like $T_i = T_s*(1+\frac{\gamma-1}{2}M^2)$ and $P_i = P_s*(1+\frac{\gamma-1}{2}M^2)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}$ where i and s stands resp. for total and static. Do you suggest that I should take directly Navier-Stokes equations and solving them in 1D (x direction + time dependency) ? Is it possible to do it in Python without difficulty ?

Comment: Is the pipe insulated, or can it exchange a significant amount of heat with its surroundings?  What is a typical set of parameters for this, like the mass flow rate of gas, the pipe length, and the pipe diameter?  The equations you wrote for the temperature and pressure assume no irreversible frictional pressure changes, which is contrary to your pressure drop equation.  What is your estimate of the Mach number for the flow in your pipe?

Comment: It can change significant amount with its surroundings. Pipe length, pipe diameter, thermal capacity of the wall are constant, but I assume that the mass flow rate is not constant as it will be regulated by the throat nozzle. I thought that the equation I wrote took into account the pressure work inside the enthalpy $h$. This equation comes from [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_principe_de_la_thermodynamique) in French. The estimate of the Mach when I have done steady calculus is around 0.15